# How do I set variables by name when calling a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

Say I've got this code:

```
function helloWorld() {
    console.log(helloText);
}
```

When I call this function, I'd like to do something like this:

```
helloWord(
    helloText = "some example text";
)
```

which of course doesn't work. But the idea is that I want to change a variable by referencing it's name when calling that function. I see numerous jQuery slideshows and stuff that do this, but I can't seem to figure it out. The closest thing I can find is this:

```
function helloWorld(helloText) {
    console.log(helloText);
}

helloWorld("some example text");
```

Which will work, but with a longer list of variables, that gets unwieldy. So how can I instead change the variable value by using its name?

Comment: `When I call this function, I'd like to do something like this` So it should be like in this jsFiddle which doesn't make much sense: http://jsfiddle.net/7c4k249n/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no keyword arguments in Javascript.  In order to mimic that behavior, you could use an object literal, like so:

```
function helloWorld(args) {
    console.log(args.helloText);
}

helloWord({
    helloText: "some example text"
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be relevant to the question.

Comment: @FelixKling how is this not relevant to the question?

Comment: *"But the idea is that I want to change a variable by referencing it's name when calling that function."* ... Maybe I'm just not understanding what the OP wants.

Comment: The question is somewhat hard to grasp, but that's exactly what he's looking for (keyword arguments).

Comment: @georg: Ah, keyword arguments makes sense. However "default parameters" is a different concept.

Comment: @FelixKling My mistake, keyword arguments is what I meant to say.  Thanks georg, I'll make the fix now

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to make it so if you don't pass any parameters it won't complain that args is not defined? If not, no problem, I can live with this.

Comment: @Rev you could check `args` for `undefined` and set it to an empty object before the `console.log` if it is.  Like so: `var args = args || {};`

Answer (score 2):

Building on the other answers, [ECMAScript 6 introduces *destructuring*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [*default parameters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). This allows you to easily simulate keyword arguments:

```
function helloWorld({helloText} = {}) {
    console.log(helloText);
}

helloWord({
    helloText: "some example text"
});
```

You can use ES6 features today with preprocessors such as [6to5](http://6to5.org/).

Comment: Es6 does not answer the questiin either

Comment: @NaeemShaikh: Why is that?

Comment: Destructuring or default parameters does not set the variables.. The way OP wanted..

Comment: If that's the case, neither does your answer.

Comment: Thats true.. Anyways but this is a good answer.. Just it does not meet the OPs needs.. And mine i am deleting.. There already is a same answer. +1 though :)